# NPE exception when reading from queue when old queue data files are deleted

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/issues/534

I am trying to implement periodic old queue file purge logic using StoreFileListener. I am using latest release net.openhft:chronicle-queue:5.16.13. The issue I am having is: after the roll cycle file gets rolled because of next cycle is active, I delete the queue file which just got released in StoreFileListener, then I create a new tailer and try to read message. It throws below NPE:

The same happens if I create a brand new queue pointing to same queue dir and create a tailer.

seeing below NPE exception when trying to implement queue file purging logic:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1198)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.readingDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1000)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.readingDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:942)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.MarshallableIn.readText(MarshallableIn.java:95)
at com.test.edge.api.queue.TestDeleteQueueFile.testQueueFileDeletionWhileInUse(TestDeleteQueueFile.java:133)
```

Test case to reproduce is below:

```
package com.test.edge.api.queue;

import net.openhft.chronicle.core.time.SetTimeProvider;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ChronicleQueue;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptAppender;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptTailer;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.RollCycles;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.StoreFileListener;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestDeleteQueueFile {

    private Path tempQueueDir;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        tempQueueDir = Files.createTempDirectory("unitTestQueueDir");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempQueueDir.toFile());
        Assert.assertFalse(tempQueueDir.toFile().exists());
        System.out.println("Deleted " + tempQueueDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Test
    public void testQueueFileDeletionWhileInUse() throws Exception {
        SetTimeProvider timeProvider = new SetTimeProvider();

        String queueName = "unitTestQueue";

        QueueStoreFileListener listener = new QueueStoreFileListener(queueName);

        try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(tempQueueDir + "/" + queueName).
                timeProvider(timeProvider).storeFileListener(listener)
                .build()) {

            ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();

            System.out.println("first index : " + queue.firstIndex());
            Assert.assertEquals(Long.MAX_VALUE, queue.firstIndex());

            //write 10 records should go to first day file
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                appender.writeText("test");
            }

            long indexAfter10Records = appender.lastIndexAppended();
            System.out.println("index after writing 10 records: " + indexAfter10Records);

            //roll to next day file
            timeProvider.advanceMillis(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


            //write 5 records in next file
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                appender.writeText("test2");
            }

            Map<String, List> queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap = listener.getQueueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap();
            Map<String, List> queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap = listener.getQueueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap();

            Assert.assertEquals(1, queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.size());
            List<String> files = queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.get(queueName);
            Assert.assertEquals(1, files.size());
            String secondFile = files.get(0);

            //other will have 1 as only first file is released
            files = queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap.get(queueName);
            Assert.assertEquals(1, files.size());
            String firstFile = files.get(0);

            Assert.assertNotEquals(firstFile, secondFile);


            long firstIndex = queue.firstIndex();


            long indexAfter5Records = appender.lastIndexAppended();
            System.out.println("index after writing 5 records: " + indexAfter5Records);

            //now lets create one reader which will read all content
            ExcerptTailer excerptTailer = queue.createTailer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Assert.assertEquals("test", excerptTailer.readText());
            }

            System.out.println("index after reading 10 records: " + excerptTailer.index());
            Assert.assertEquals(firstIndex, excerptTailer.index() - 10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Assert.assertEquals("test2", excerptTailer.readText());
            }

            System.out.println("index after reading 5 records: " + excerptTailer.index());
            Assert.assertEquals(indexAfter5Records, excerptTailer.index() - 1);

            //lets delete first file
            System.out.println("Deleting first release file: " + firstFile);
            Files.delete(Paths.get(firstFile));


            long firstIndex3 = queue.firstIndex();
            Assert.assertEquals(firstIndex, firstIndex3);

            // and create a tailer it should only read
            //data in second file
            ExcerptTailer excerptTailer2 = queue.createTailer();
            System.out.println("index before reading 5: " + excerptTailer2.index());

            //AFTER CREATING A BRAND NEW TAILER, BELOW ASSERTION ALSO FAILS
            //WAS EXPECTING THAT TAILER CAN READ FROM START OF QUEUE BUT INDEX IS LONG.MAX

            //Assert.assertEquals(indexAfter5Records -5, excerptTailer2.index() -1);

            //BELOW THROWS NPE, WAS EXPECTING THAT WE CAN READ FROM SECOND DAILY QUEUE FILE
            System.out.println("excerptTailer2: " + excerptTailer2.peekDocument());
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Assert.assertEquals("test2", excerptTailer2.readText());
            }

            //SAME ERROR WHEN CREATING A BRAND NEW QUEUE AND TRYING TO READ IT

//            // create brand new queue and read see how it behaves
//            ChronicleQueue queue2 =  SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(tempQueueDir + "/" + queueName).
//                    timeProvider(timeProvider).storeFileListener(listener)
//                    .build();
//
//            long firstIndex2 = queue2.firstIndex();
//            Assert.assertNotEquals(firstIndex, firstIndex2);
//            Assert.assertNotEquals(indexAfter5Records, firstIndex2);
//
//            ExcerptTailer excerptTailer3 = queue.createTailer();
//            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
//                Assert.assertEquals("test2", excerptTailer3.readText());
//            }

        }

    }

    final class QueueStoreFileListener implements StoreFileListener {

        private String queueName;
        private Map<String, List> queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap = new HashMap<>();
        private Map<String, List> queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap = new HashMap<>();

        public QueueStoreFileListener(String queueName) {
            this.queueName = queueName;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReleased(int cycle, File file) {
            System.out.println("onReleased called cycle: " + cycle + "file: " + file);

            List<String> files = queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap.get(queueName);
            if (files == null) {
                files = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            String fileAbsPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if (!files.contains(fileAbsPath)) {
                files.add(fileAbsPath);
            }
            queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap.put(queueName, files);

            //update acquire file map
            List<String> acqfiles = queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.get(queueName);
            acqfiles.remove(file.getAbsolutePath());
            queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.put(queueName, acqfiles);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAcquired(int cycle, File file) {
            System.out.println("onAcquired called cycle: " + cycle + "file: " + file);

            List<String> files = queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.get(queueName);
            if (files == null) {
                files = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            String fileAbsPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if (!files.contains(fileAbsPath)) {
                files.add(fileAbsPath);
            }

            queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap.put(queueName, files);


        }

        public Map<String, List> getQueueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap() {
            return queueToRollFilesOnAcquireMap;
        }

        public Map<String, List> getQueueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap() {
            return queueToRollFilesOnReleaseMap;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
Assert.assertEquals(indexAfter5Records -5, excerptTailer2.index() -1);
```

`indexAfter5Records` is

```
0x100000004
```

as expected. This is because the top 32-bit hold the cycle number which is `1` and the lower bits holds the record in cycle number which is `4` which is the 5-th record starting at `0`.

The `excerptTailer2.index()` should wind to the start. On my Windows machine, this is `0` as Windows doesn't always allow you to delete a memory mapped file until the process has existed. On Linux, this isn't a problem.

In my case, as the file couldn't be deleted, I used

```
excerptTailer2.moveToIndex(0x1_0000_0000L);
```

and it read the expected text messages.

There was a version recently where readText/writeText was broken but it should be fixed in 5.16.15.

If you are looking for a very stable version I suggest 4.15.7. If you want to use the latest version, I would take a version which doesn't have another release the next day ;)

We are looking to make 5.16.x our stable version soon, release a 6.17.x which will include Java 11 support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. I am testing on OSX, so I think memory mapped file should be deleted, correct? What  I am seeing is that when I create another tailer on the same queue `ExcerptTailer excerptTailer2 = queue.createTailer();
System.out.println("index before reading 5: " + excerptTailer2.index());` excerptTailer2.index() has Long.MAX_VALUE , is this expected?  Use case I am trying is "lets say we are reading a queue file for a roll cycle at the same time the file got deleted due to file purge policy by some other thread, so the above test is trying to simulate and getting NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I found a solution. Try to do refresh of directory listing before creating a tailer. E.g., you could add

```
queue.refreshDirectlyListing();
```

before

```
ExcerptTailer excerptTailer2 = queue.createTailer();
```

It will force to reread list of queue files. And also you can check implementation of this method to see, why listing is not refreshed by default:

```
    private void setFirstAndLastCycle() {
    long now = time.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now <= firstAndLastCycleTime) {
        return;
    }

    firstCycle = directoryListing.getMinCreatedCycle();
    lastCycle = directoryListing.getMaxCreatedCycle();

    firstAndLastCycleTime = now;
}
```